# Use custom DataTemplate in XF with XAML

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

This code is working :

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSourcePrimary}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>

        <ViewCell>
          <ViewCell.View>
            <StackLayout Padding="15, 5, 15, 5" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
              <Image Source="{Binding IconSource}" Aspect="AspectFit" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
              <Label Text="{Binding Title}" VerticalOptions="Center" />
            </StackLayout>
          </ViewCell.View>
        </ViewCell>

      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

But I would like to seperate a part into a class like this :

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSourcePrimary}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>

        <local:MenuListCell Title="{Binding Title}" IconSource="{Binding IconSource}" />

      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

But I have an error :

> No Property of Text Name found

I implement the class MenuListCell in a xaml file with this code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ViewCell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Test.MenuListCell">

    <ViewCell.View>
        <StackLayout Padding="15, 5, 15, 5" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
          <Image Source="{Binding IconSource}" Aspect="AspectFit" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
          <Label Text="{Binding Title}" VerticalOptions="Center" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ViewCell.View>

</ViewCell>
```

Do you have a solution ?
Do we need to create a c# file .cs in order to implement the properties or we can do it in xaml ?

Answer (score 1):

If you bind the `MenuListCell` always to the same type of objects, you just have to change

```
<local:MenuListCell Title="{Binding Title}" IconSource="{Binding IconSource}" />
```

to

```
<local:MenuListCell />
```

The Datacontext of the cell is your item. So the `Title` in

```
 <Label Text="{Binding Title}" VerticalOptions="Center" />
```

is a property of the list item.

Comment: Ok but with this method, i get this error :
"System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Have you got an idea ?
The same code with ViewCell directly is working

Comment: Without a stacktrace, it's not easy. It should work if the data is correct.